# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql-server-2005

hi 
i have a problem on converting datetime from character string on createddate and leavestartdate column.....

**Table structure   createdby varchar(30),createddate datetime, leavetype varchar(30), leavestartdate varchar(30), status varchar(30)**

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_SearchLeave]
@createdby      varchar(30) = null ,
@createddate    DateTime    = null ,
@leavetype      varchar(30) = null ,
@leavestartdate varchar(30) = null ,
@status         varchar(30) = null

As
Begin

if @createddate is not null and Len(@createddate) = 0 set @createddate = null
if @leavetype = 'Select' set @leavetype = null
if @leavestartdate is not null and Len(@leavestartdate) = 0 set @leavestartdate = null
if @status = 'Select' set @status = null

Select leaverequestid,leaveenddate,leavetype,leavestartdate,status
from LeaveRequest
where 
       (@createdby is null or createdby like '%' + @createdby + '%')
  and  (@createddate is null or createddate like '%' + @createddate + '%')
  and  (@leavetype is null or leavetype like '%' + @leavetype + '%')
  and  (@leavestartdate is null or leavestartdate like '%' + @leavestartdate + '%')
  and  (@status is null or status like '%' + @status + '%')
End
```

when i execute this sp as a input like 
exec sp_SearchLeave '','','','12/15/2010',''

it displays the error message like
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_SearchLeave, Line 26
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Bradford's answer is undoubtedly correct, but it's also worth knowing that you're using an unsafe string format for dates also - the safe format for date (without time) is `YYYYMMDD`, e.g. `'20101215'`

Comment: @brad Thats right but i passing a date from front end ASP.net....

Answer (score 3):

The reason is likely the `like` statement.  You're treating a `datetime` parameter (@createddate) as a string by appending `%` to it, which you cannot do.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are attempting to do.  Performing "like" statement on a date, even one converted to a string, is unusual.  Are you attempting to search for a specific month, year, or other date part?

Comment: That part is understandable.  What is this "like" clause used for?  Are you attempting to ignore that time portion of the column in the database?  If so, then you can compare the date on a single-day range [e.g., DateColumn >= @DateParameter and DateColumn < dateadd(day, 1, @DateParameter)]

Comment: okay if i going to pass the date into database then it should search the exact match date and retrieve the record this what i want.... can u understand this one.

Comment: As in simply, DateColumn = @DateParameter?  If so, then there is no need to manipulate the date parameter at all, unless there is any specific validation of the parameter needed.  So, you can drop the "like" operator and go with a straight equality comparison.

Comment: @brad : The straight equality comparison doesn't work but the  DateColumn >= @DateParameter and DateColumn < dateadd(day, 1, @DateParameter)] this will works fine.. Thanks for ur answer Friend.